# build and publish .net Web App programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, build, build-automation, publish

I'm building an application that needs to be able to, on a command, publish itself to a specified directory.

I'm looking for something like

```
System.BuildSystem.Build(<project file>, 'release');
System.BuildSystem.Publish(<project file>, <destination folder>);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: But you just answered your own question!

Comment: How did I answer my own question? Those are not valid C# functions. My question was, what C# functions would accomplish this pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at msbuild or nant.  Personally, I use msbuild to push releases to our QA environment and create packages to be rolled out to production.

Your application could, for example, call batch files that run msbuild scripts to produce and publish builds.

Comment: The nice thing about MSBuild is your proj files are already in MSBuild format, so chances are they will drop right in and just work.

Comment: I was hoping there was something in the language / framework. I'm always hesitant to use System.Diagnostics.Process.*

Comment: I've never heard of anything in the framework to do that.  Launching a separate app to do the build should be manageable though.  One app that uses MSBuild like that is CruiseControl.NET.  We use that at my work on our build server, and it just runs msbuild as a separate process.  From there you can compile, version, publish (we do this using the Web Deployment projects), do web.config transforms.  It really works well for us.